# Count uniques by multiple columnar data in a gz file with duplicates

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, grep

I'm working with fairly large tsv zip files whereby each file has 3 columns only. I would like to count the number of unique occurrences for a particular regex (which is contained in column 3) across all files. 
How do I make sure the count number in the output removes any duplicates based on values contained in column 1?

Tried both of these, but not sure if they are correct:

```
zgrep -c ",80447," AU_AAID_201812*.tsv.gz | uniq -c
zgrep -c ",80447," AU_AAID_201812*.tsv.gz
```

I want to get the unique count number so that if:

- Column 1/Row 1 = "xyz123" and Column 3/Row 1 = ",80447,"
- Column 1/Row 2 = "xyz123" and Column 3/Row 2 = ",80447,"

Then my output would be still be "1".

Comment: I'm confused. Are you counting the unique col1, or unique col1+col3?

Comment: I'd like to count the number of uniques in col3, while removing duplicates from col1.
For example:
Row 1: col 1 = abc321 / col3 = 80447
Row 2: col 1 = abc321 / col 3 = 80447,80193,81992.

Count needs to be = 1

Comment: @DFan : Col 3 can contain more than one value? What are those 3 values after 80447? Next column values?

Comment: @Inian, that's right. Col3 sometimes contains multiple values. I only want to count specifically "80447".

Comment: @DFan Isn't that the same example you gave in the question? Can you show a more complete sample and the final result you want from it?

Comment: What's the difference between "counting uniques" and "removing duplicates"?

Comment: yes, same example. essentially means the same, i just want the count of the uniques while making sure no double counts due to duplicates in column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cut` to get just column1 and column3, use `sort -u` to remove duplicates, and then use `wc -l` to get the count:

```
zgrep ',80447,' AU_AAID_201812*.tsv.gz | cut -d, -f1,3 | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. How would you include the search function ",80447," into this command line?

Comment: Pipe it through `grep ,80447,` before `cut`.

Comment: Or use `zgrep` as you did in the question. It wasn't clear how that was related to the rest of the question.